# how to link AbstractAccountAuthenticator with AccountAuthenticatorActivity in android

Tags: android

The official documentation says to return a bundle in addAccount method. What is it for?

```
@Override
public Bundle addAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType, String authTokenType, String[] requiredFeatures, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {

    Log.v("TAG", "addAccount()");
    final Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AuthenticatorActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, response);
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, intent);


    return bundle;
}
```

i can't get the actual workflow of this AbstractAccountAuthenticator. Should i start AccountAuthenticatorActivity as the launcher Activity, and call the AbstractAccountAuthenticator by passing the context of the current activity? If so when will the the addAccount method called? Where should i make the API call for creating the account in my backend? Where will AbstractAccountAuthenticator save token? How should i access that token from AbstractAccountAuthenticator?

Answer (score 0):

Its called when user trying to add account from settings.